# Moment.js unix timestamp to display time ago always in minutes

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

I am using Moment.js and would like to convert unix timestamps to (always) display minutes ago from the current time. E.g.) 4 mins ago, 30 mins ago, 94 mins ago, ect.

Right now I am using:

```
moment.unix(d).fromNow()
```

But this does not always display in minutes e.g.) an hour ago, a day ago, ect. I have tried using .asMinutes() but I believe this only words with moment.duration().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this is possible with native Moment methods, but you can easily make your own Moment extension:

```
moment.fn.minutesFromNow = function() {
    return Math.floor((+new Date() - (+this))/60000) + ' mins ago';
}
//then call:
moment.unix(d).minutesFromNow();
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/GF4Mr/3/)

Note that other moment methods won't be chainable after `minutesFromNow()` as my extension returns a string.

**edit:**

Extension with fixed plural (0 min**s**, 1 min, 2 min**s**):

```
moment.fn.minutesFromNow = function() {
    var r = Math.floor((+new Date() - (+this))/60000);
    return r + ' min' + ((r===1) ? '' : 's') + ' ago';
}
```

You can as well replace "min" with "minute" if you prefer the long form.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/GF4Mr/4/)

Comment: nice.. but... How do I bring in future timestamp? This returns me the minutes negative

Answer (score 2):

Just modify the "find" function in the moment.js code, so that it returns minutes:

```
from : function (time, withoutSuffix) {

  return moment.duration(this.diff(time)).asMinutes();

}
```

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/FTnNk/).

...or, even better. Just add this as a new function called "fromNowInMinutes".